# Materializing workspace using a maven plugin

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, tycho

In order to be able to test my eclipse plugins, I use a workspace with some predefined projects. With Buckminster, I could import these projects in the wokspace before running the tests. Is there a way to do that with maven?

I imagine that a maven plugin could use the m2eclipse API to import these existing projects from a pom. Being a Maven newbie, I hope someone can point me to existing code that does that or something similar.

Comment: It seems questionable that you want to use Maven for this. Setting up test data seems to be something that can be easily be coded in a JUnit `@Before`. I wouldn't introduce a dependency from your tests to the build system for this.

Comment: Ok, I understand and I will do something like you suggested instead. Thanks!